# How to change layout of spinner in Android

Tags: android

[image]

When O click on this spinner it gives a big dropdown:

[image]

I want a very small view as in the second image. Just like dropdowns in ASP.NET. Like this with width little more reduced.

[image]

I used the following code. Any help to change the view of second image will be appreciated.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
       this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Did you used custom_spiner.xml as I given? If yes then set height and width of that textview.

Comment: i have set but only text height and width reduces....but not view as above in 3rd image

Answer (score 10):

**This is a good article :** [Customizing the Action Bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)

And also you can try this :

Design you own customized drawable for spinner background and apply to it.
For spinnerbackground.xml images you can refer the images from the SDK. recreate the images as per your design requirements

> "Android-sdk\platforms\android-9\data\res\drawable-hdpi\*.png"

spinnerbackground.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled_focused" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled" />
</selector>
```

then for spinner widget apply your custom drawable:

```
<Spinner android:background="@drawable/spinnerbackground"
         android:id="@+id/spinnerIDr"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </Spinner>
```

**Edited :**

```
<Spinner android:background="@drawable/spinnerbackground"
         android:id="@+id/spinnerIDr"
         android:popupBackground="@drawable/popup_background"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </Spinner>
```

where popup_background is : 
[image]

and

Design your custom layout for spinner texts as (name : custom_spiner.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
```

and use it as

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spiner);
```

in your code.

Edited 2:

if you want to do this using java code read about [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

And may be useful : [custom-spinner](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html)

Comment: i think this not a good idea...i am changing inbulit things...also if i debug from some other system..it wont show the changes...customize the view using code...

Comment: @Rockin see my updates. And be clear what you are asking. Do you want to do this with java code?

Comment: i want to reduce the size of the second image...width and all

Comment: Which image? Is that popup_background? you don't need to change size of that image, just put android:dropDownHeight="100dip" and      android:dropDownWidth="50dip" to spinner.

Comment: android:dropDownHeight="20dipandroid:dropDownWidth="20dip" i dont see option coming in <spinner...the image with 1,2,3 etc...i want reduce its width and height...like asp.net dropdown

Comment: Can you post that image, as what you want, and in current what is result image?

Comment: @Rockin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2309/discussion-between-pankaj-and-rockin)

Comment: This may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033422/how-can-i-manage-the-height-of-android-spinner-items

Comment: Did you able to achieve width and height like asp.net dropdown. I am also trying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps. I have already implemented this.

(1) Do not use spinner. Instead use a button with background set to "@android:drawable/btn_dropdown". This button will look exactly same as native spinner. If you want it to look any different use your own resource.

(2) You need to override dialog class and invoke it on button click.
In the constructor of the extended Dialog class, you can use your own layout resource.

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.dropdownlist);
```

You can also change window look and feel using following code

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.width = dlgWidth;
lp.height = dlgHeight;
lp.dimAmount = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(mBackgroundResId);
```

(3) You can have a list view in your custom layout and on "OnItemClickListener" of the list, dismiss the dialog and do what you need to do further.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute in the Spinner tag

> android:dropDownWidth="150dp"

Comment: where does this get added?

Comment: <Spinner ...
                android:dropDownWidth="50dp"
                 />