# How to change Android spinner text color?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I know this question has been asked a lot (see: [How to customize a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android),
[How to change layout of spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006081/how-to-change-layout-of-spinner-in-android), [How to change spinner text size and text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color), [How to change spinner text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312043/how-to-change-spinner-text-color))

All the answers suggest to create a custom_spinner.xml file to accomplish this task. This file must be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/#FFFFFF" />
```

However, no one says where to locate this file. In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859442/5616178 says this file must be in Drawable folder, but when I do that, an "Element TextView must be declared" error is raised by Android Studio. When I locate it in the layout folder, the R.layout won't resolve it either.

Thank you for your answers.

**EDIT**

I was able to solve the problem. As many of you said, the file must be located inside the `res/layout` since it's a layout resource. At first, my code looked like this:

```
citiesSpinner.setAdapter(
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(SignUp.this,
                    android.R.layout.custom_spinner,
                    cityNames)
);
```

When I declared the adapter outside the constructor, i.e.:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SignUp.this,
                    R.layout.custom_spinner,
                    cityNames);
citiesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The R class was able to resolve the layout. I don't know why that happens, it would be useful if someone can explain it. Thank you again for your answers!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 2):

> However, no one says where to locate this file.

That is a layout resource. It would go in `res/layout/` by default.

> When I locate it in the layout folder, the R.layout won't resolve it either.

Then you have some other problem. For example, perhaps there is a bug in your layout resource that is preventing the `R` class from being regenerated.

Comment: It'd be nice if you link to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: As I said, when I locate the file in `res/layout`, an "Element TextView must be declared" error is raised by Android Studio.

Comment: @GénessisSánchez: That is not what your question has. Your question indicates that you are getting that error when you put that XML in a drawable resource ("this file must be in Drawable folder, but when I do that, an "Element TextView must be declared" error is raised by Android Studio"). This makes sense, as that is not a valid drawable resource. It *is* a valid layout resource, at least insofar as `<TextView>` is a valid element for a layout resource.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your resource file must be in the layout folder
2. Your `android:id="@android:id/text1"` need to be `android:id="@+id/text1"`
3. Just declare your array like the links above recommended :

   `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.custom_spinner,yourArray);`